# Display Bootstrap Modal for Selected Table Item

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a simple buddy list for a web application. I'm looping through an SQL table to retrieve the current user's buddy list. Each row in the table has a button to display a modal of the selected user's ID. The current issue I'm having is that it's only showing the modal for the last user in the list, for everyone else it doesn't pop up. I need the modal to pop up for each user I click on and display that user's ID.
Example:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
// Full SQL retrieval omitted above 
$buddyUid = '';
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $buddyUid = $row['buddy_uid'];
                                                                   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $buddyUid . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <button type='button' onclick='javascript:selectBuddy($(this)); ' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#modal-" . $buddyUid . "'><i class='fas fa-share-square'></i></button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?=$buddyUid?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <?= $buddyUid?>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectBuddy(buddy) {
    $('#modal-' + buddy).modal('show'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this) refers to the element in the DOM to which the onclick attribute belongs:

in your case to get only buddy_id just change onclick event

from this

`...onclick='javascript:selectBuddy($(this));'...`

to this

`...onclick='javascript:selectBuddy(".$buddyUid.");'...`

also change your Modal id from

`<div class="modal fade" id="modal-<?=$buddyUid?>" ...`

to

`<div class="modal fade" id="modal-buddy" ....`

then javascript code like this

```
function selectBuddy(buddy) {
    $('#modal-buddy').find('.modal-body').html(buddy);
    $('#modal-buddy').modal('show'); 
}
```

Comment: I attempted to modify it to your suggestion, but it's still yielding the same result.

Comment: try to `alert(('#modal-' + buddy))`  inside `selectBuddy()` and see if it does alert correct `modal + id`

Comment: I added that and it does show in the alert the correct ID for each of them.

Comment: ok, then your `<!-- Modal -->` is that echoing inside `foreach()` looping or not ?

Comment: I'm sorry but could you clarify on that?

Comment: Never mind I think it doesn't on `foreach()` so I've update my answer so can try it

Comment: Thank you very much, your updated answer solved the issue for me. I appreciate it.